# Django Rest Framework- How to send data as strings

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

I want to send all the data in a response as string, like in database id is stored as integers but I want to send it as string in response.
eg: I have the response as

```
{
"categories": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "xya",
        "quantity": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to be as:

```
{
"categories": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "category": "xya",
        "quantity": "25"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using ModelSerializer to send all the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to convert int to str using the `to_representation` method of your model serializer.

```py
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # other fields    

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """ Override `to_representation` method """
        repr = super().to_representation(instance)
        repr['id'] = str(repr['id'])
        repr['quantity'] = str(repr['quantity'])    
        return repr
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a loop to change every value, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly define `id` field in your serializer to be `CharField()`

Like this

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # other fields
    id = serializers.CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('id', ..... other fields)
```

Comment: thanks, actually I had to change every field in a large table, so this method would have been a lot of work, anyways Thanks